# Kendo Editor not showing toolbar in Razor page using MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I am trying to use the Kendo Editor in a simple Razor page. I put in the code from the Telerik site for both initializing the Editor and for the Basic Configuration as seen on the
https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/html-helpers/editors/editor/overview page. In neither case does the Toolbar display no matter if I click inside the editable area or not. For example, this is the page containing the Basic Configuration:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model TYX.Entities.Banner

@{
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create Alert Banner</title>
</head>
<body>
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

    @(Html.Kendo().Editor()
    .Name("editor")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%;height:440px" })
    .Value(@<text>
               <p>
                   Kendo UI Editor allows your users to edit HTML in a familiar, user-friendly way.
               </p>
            </text>)
    )

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // The Name() of the Editor is used to get its client-side instance.
            var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
        });
    </script>

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output page contains the Editor text edit area, but nothing I do makes the Toolbar show.
[image]

I have another Razor page from a different project that displays the toolbar without any problem and it is displayed as soon as the page loads. Here is the page code for that instance:

```
    <div class="card-body card-padding p-t-0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form id="bannerForm">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
                    <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                        <label class="col-xl-2 col-form-label">Banner Body</label>
                        <div class="col-xl">
                            <div id="banner-body" class="k-content editor">
                                @(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(m => m.Body)
                                    .Name("Body")
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%; height:420px", aria_label = "Body" })
                                    .Tools(tools => tools
                                        .Clear()
                                        .Formatting()
                                        .Bold().Italic().Underline()
                                        .CleanFormatting()
                                        .JustifyLeft().JustifyCenter().JustifyRight()
                                        .InsertUnorderedList().InsertOrderedList()
                                        .Outdent().Indent()
                                        .CreateLink().Unlink()
                                        .ViewHtml()
                                        .TableEditing()
                                    )
                                )
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-xl-2 col-form-label">Is Active</label>
                        <div class="col-xl">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActive)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
            <button class="btn btn-primary px-3"
                    type="button"
                    onclick="saveBanner();">
                Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the output:
[image]

Any idea why my toolbar is not showing? Also, I pasted the code from the working page into my page and it doesn't show the toolbar either.

Comment: if you open your browser dev tools, are there any console errors showing up when the toolbar doesn't display?

Comment: You're missing script references in the `head` tag to `kendo.all.min.js` and `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js`. There also isn't any references for the theme to `kendo.common.min.css` and `kendo.[themeName].min.css`.